# batch - pass input directly into if sentence

Tags: batch-file

to clarify.. this is how the raw code looks like at this point

```
echo[
echo         1 - Scan with service guess (-sF,-sV,-pN)
echo         2 - Quick nmap scan (May be blocked by firewalls)
echo         3 - Try to avoid Firewall (Very Slow)
echo         4 - Operation system (Will attempt to guess Operation System)
echo         5 - Choose own parameters (inactive at this time)
echo         6 - Go Back
echo[
set /p scan=Which kind of scan? 
if /I "%scan%"=="1" nmap.exe %target% -sF -T5 -Pn -sV --traceroute
if /I "%scan%"=="2" nmap.exe %target% -sS
if /I "%scan%"=="3" nmap.exe %target% --scan-delay 1 --badsum
if /I "%scan%"=="4" nmap.exe %target% -O
if /I "%scan%"=="5" goto :para
if /I "%scan%"=="6" goto :choice
if /I "%scan%"=="" goto :scan
pause
goto :scan
:para
cls
Echo put in the parameters for nmap to use
set /P para= which parameters to use?
if /I "%para%"=="*what should be here" nmap.exe %target% %para%
if /I "%para%=="" goto :para
```

what I wanna do is if user choose to input own paramters (5) it goes to :para
then ask the user to input own parameters for nmap to use.

so my question is - what should be in between the quotes in the 'if /I "%para%"=="*what should be here"' sentence to pass that input directly into the nmap line ..

Should any wonder what the 'if /I "%para%"=="" goto :para' the intend is to prevent error if the user just press enter without writing anything..

Comment: If %para% is blank then why use it after %target%.

Comment: %para% is not blank :) %para% is the parameters the user wants nmap to use as an example "nmap xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -sS -sV -p 23,80,443"

Comment: That's fair enough, although my comment was pre-edit when you had `if /I "%para%"=="" nmap.exe %target% %para%`

Comment: Ok, np. m8 thax for the answer anyway :) I'm pretty new at this type of coding, so it's very crude at this point. Mostly i try to find answers by Google but couldn't find any that would solve my problem in this case.. so I hope you will forgive with me :)

Comment: Actually your code does nothing, there are just remarks and labels...

Comment: @aschipfl - I'm not sure what you mean .. can you please eloborate..
and maybe tell me what I need to do to make the if /I "%para%" sentence to directly pass on what the user inputs

Comment: `REM` defines a remark in `cmd`/batch scripting; almost every line of your code begins with `REM`. `:Label` is a jump label...

Comment: @aschipfl, Thank you for the answer. Yes that is because I commented it out of the program so it would not run until I find an soloutin for my problem.. :) . look further Down the page to get an better idear of the code :)..

Comment: Why the hell did you move your question into an answer post?? Please revert that!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "quote both sides of the comparison" and use the *contents* of the variable `para`

```
if /I "%para%"=="*user input"
```

strangely, exactly the same way as you `if` against `scan`...

(I've no idea why you are "quoting every line". Seems odd - and I'm not even going to try it...)

---

Ah - you appear to want to check `para` for validity.

```
Echo put in the parameters for nmap to use
set "para="
set /P para= which parameters to use?
if NOT DEFINED para goto para
call :check %para%
if not defined error nmap.exe %target% %para%&goto :eof
echo %error% is invalid
goto para

:check
set "error="
if "%~1"=="" goto :eof
if "%~1"=="-sS" goto parmok
if "%~1"=="-Pn" goto parmok
...
set "error=%~1"
goto :eof

:parmok
shift
goto check
```

First, clear `para` before requesting input. If the user presses just <kbd>Enter</kbd> then `para` will remain **unchanged**, it will not be **cleared**.

Next, check whether `para` is defined. If it is undefined, then the user pressed just <kbd>Enter</kbd> so ask for input again (?Possibly go to SCAN?)

Please note that the colon in a `goto` is not required **except** with the special instruction `goto :eof` which means "go to the end of the batch file"

Once we have determined that `para` is not empty, just `call :check` and pass the contents of `para`. This executes a subroutine called `check`. If the subroutine name has no colon, then the subroutine is in `check.bat`. If it has a colon, then the subroutine is "internal" - a label within this batch code.

The routine `:check` will set a variable `error` to be either empty (if there are no errors) or *something* which will be the erroneous parameter. Therefore, if `error` is not defined, execute `nmap` with the entered parameters and then (goto :eof to terminate the batch - I don't know what you want to do here...) - note that `&` concatenates instructions.

If `error` is set, then show it and go back to the label `:para` (you could possibly put  `pause` in here, else the `cls` will wipe out the message)

Finally we have the `:check` routine.

`%~1` means "remove any enclosing quotes from the first parameter supplied to the subroutine"

So - set `error` to *nothing* then check `"%~1"` against each of the valid parameter elements - I showed just 2 as I don't know the requirments here. Just add more checks in place of `...`

If the parameter is found to be valid, go to the label `:parmok`. If it fails all of the tests, put it into `error` and terminate the routine (which returns to the line after the `call :check` with `error` set non-empty, indicating an error).

At `:parmok`, we use a `shift` which drops the first parameter and shifts the reaminder along one place. Going back to `:check` tests the new first parameter, until all of the parameters have been checked.

Comment: the quotes was just to get the chat box to accept me writing code directly in the question ..
I have tried to use the 'if /I "%para%"=="" nmap %target% %para%'

Comment: thank you for the answer, can you elborate you answer a bit I am not sure on what you mean. If it was an already predefined input as just -sS or someting I would know how to do it. But nmap have a lot of parameters that can be used and therefor a lot of combinations. I could solve it just by opening a new cmd prombt as this would do 'if /i "%scan%"=="5"' start nmap.exe but I would like it all to happend with the same cmd prombt. Hope you understand what I mean and can help me out